# What is the best way to nest 2 inline if in React 15?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I wanted to know if its possible to do nested 2 ifs in reactjs jsx?
I have tried various different ways and I am unable to get it to work.
I have tried with just a  element it works. As soon as i put  and  element my code breaks.

```
              <div>
                {
                  (() => {
                    if (VerticalRole === "Software Developer")

                    <div>
                      <label>GITHUB ACCOUNT</label>
                      <div className="value">
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="github_url"
                          className="lowercase"
                          defaultValue={this.props.talent.github_url}
                          onChange={this.onChangeInput.bind(this)}
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    if (MarketVetical === "Creative/Marketing")

                    <div>
                      <label>Portfolio Website</label>
                      <div className="value">
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="github_url"
                          className="lowercase"
                          defaultValue= 
                          {this.props.talent.personal_website}
                          onChange={this.onChangeInput.bind(this)}
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  })()
                }
              </div>
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with a ternary operator :

```
<div>
  {
    VerticalRole === "Software Developer" ?
      <div>
        <label>GITHUB ACCOUNT</label>
        <div className="value">
          <input
            type="text"
            name="github_url"
            className="lowercase"
            defaultValue={this.props.talent.github_url}
            onChange={this.onChangeInput.bind(this)}
            />
          </div>
      </div>
    : MarketVetical === "Creative/Marketing" ?
      <div>
        <label>Portfolio Website</label>
        <div className="value">
          <input
            type="text"
            name="github_url"
            className="lowercase"
            defaultValue= 
            {this.props.talent.personal_website}
            onChange={this.onChangeInput.bind(this)}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    : null
  }
</div>
```

Comment: This worked and i see how  ternary operator is helpfull